# Map state object with array as values

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

We have the following state in react:

```
state = {
  thumbnail: [],
  title: [],
}
```

Which gets set after we retrieve some data from `themoviedb` api, like

```
axios.get(
    `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&with_genres=28,99&api_key=${apiKey}`
)
.then(res => {
    const thumbnail = res.data.results.map(res => res.poster_path)
    const title = res.data.results.map(res => res.original_title)

                this.setState({ thumbnail, title })
                // console.log(posterPath);
})
```

So our state will look like :

```
thumbnail: ['url1', 'url2'] // 20 entries
title: ['title1', 'title2'] // 20 entries, too
```

Then I want to render a list which has to take these two props as values and Display them, but I don't know how to, what I've tried is:

```
{Object.entries(this.state).map((url,i) => {
    console.log(url[1]);
    return(
        <ImageCard 
            key={i}
            source={{uri: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342'+url.thumbnail}}
            style={{width: width * 0.3, height: height * 0.3, margin: 3}}
            title={url.title}
        />
    );
})}
```

But it doesn't work, i wanna map over the whole state object So i won't have to do two maps, anyone has any ideea how can I map over this data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the thumbnail and title are related with each other, I would keep only one array inside the state like this:

```
state = {
  data: []
}
```

Changing to axios.get like this:

```
axios.get(
  `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&with_genres=28,99&api_key=${apiKey}`
)
  .then(res => {

    let temp = res.data.results.map(item => {
      return {
        thumbnail: item.poster_path,
        title: item.original_title
      }
    })

    this.setState({ data: temp })
  })
```

And displaying the ImageCard like this:

```
this.state.data.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <ImageCard
      key={index}
      source={{ uri: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342' + item.thumbnail }}
      style={{ width: width * 0.3, height: height * 0.3, margin: 3 }}
      title={item.title}
    />
  );
})
```

Comment: yeah i just did!

Answer (score 1):

You could just do the following instead of 2 maps, if the 2 arrays will be the same length

```
{this.state.title.map((title, i) => {
  return(
    <ImageCard 
        key={i}
        source={{uri: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342'+this.state.thumbnail[i]}}
        style={{width: width * 0.3, height: height * 0.3, margin: 3}}
        title={title}
    />
  );
})}
```